# Plot not showing for animation matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to animate the numpy array C3, this is an array with one channel of electrode data and I want to plot it in real time using matplotlib.

I have created my update function but nothing is printing out, I though the the syntax is you pass `i` through to loop through the plots and the FuncAnimation should do the rest.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_skip = 50

def update_plot(i):
    plt.cla()
    
    plt.plot(C3[i:i+data_skip], t[i:i+data_skip])
    plt.scatter(C3[i], t[i], marker='o', color='r')
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), update_plot, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [`plt.cla()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.cla.html), it will clear current axes. Every time you plot something on figure, `plt.cla()` then clears it.

You could confirm it by the following minimul example. It plots nothing

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

C3 = np.linspace(0.5, 10, 100)
t = np.linspace(0.5, 10, 100)

plt.plot(C3, t)

plt.cla()

plt.show()
```

Matplotlib documentation have an example to write [animation code: simple_anim.py](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/simple_anim.html). You'd better explicitly declare `fig` and `ax`.

```py
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

C3 = np.linspace(0.5, 10, 100)
t = np.linspace(0.5, 10, 100)

data_skip = 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


def update_plot(i):
    ax.plot(C3[i:i+data_skip], t[i:i+data_skip])
    ax.scatter(C3[i], t[i], marker='o', color='r')


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I make sure the plot stays the same colour every time it updates?

Comment: @PoChenLiu Pass a color argument to `ax.plot()` like what `ax.scatter()` does.