# ax[1] figure is not shown

Tags: python, matplotlib, nested-loops, axis

I am trying to creat a **multiple figure** within a loop. The first loop creats the upper figure (`ax[0]`) by adding certain plots (two in this case), meanwhile the second one (`ax[1]`) creats the lower figure, with just one plot.

After the first iteration of the second loop, the figure is saved and the second figure(`ax[1]`) is reset. The process is repeated until last iteration of the second loop is reached.

```
for i in objetos:          # Each object contains first upper figure info as lists of lists
    data_sets = i.getProcesados()   # For labeling
    fechas = i.getFechas()          # List of dates
    promedios = i.getPromedios()    # List of values
    agregado = i.getAgregado()      # For labeling
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (18,13), sharex = True)
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
    
# FIRST LOOP -----> CREATES THE UPPER FIGURE ---------------------------------
    for fecha,valor,label in zip(fechas,promedios,data_sets):
        ax[0].plot_date(fecha, valor, label = label)
        ax[0].legend(framealpha=1, borderpad = 0.7, frameon = True,
        labelspacing = 0.7, fontsize = 17, loc='best')
            
    # First axis (ax[0]) configuration:
    x_minima = int(min([j[0] for j in fechas]))
    x_maxima = int(max([j[-1] for j in fechas]))
    ax[0].set_xticks(range((x_minima),(int(x_maxima)),60))
    ax[0].set_xlim(x_minima,x_maxima)
    ax[0].tick_params(labelsize=17)
    months = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=2)
    months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m')
    ax[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
    ax[0].xaxis.set_minor_formatter(months_fmt)
    ax[0].grid(axis='y')
    ax[0].grid(which='minor')
    ax[0].set_title((i.getAgregado() + " (" + "Zona de " + zona + ")" + "\n"), fontsize = 24)
    ax[0].set_ylabel("Deformación (cm)", fontsize = 22, labelpad = 11)

# SECOND LOOP -----> CREATES THE LOWER FIGURE ---------------------------------
    
    piezos, registros = Piezo.EsteAgregado(agregado)    # Object provinding information

    for l in piezos.Piezometro:
        serie = registros.loc[l]    
        dates = list(serie.Fechas)                  # List of dates
        values = list(serie.Cota_piezométrica)      # List of values
        etiqueta = 'P - ' + str(l)                  # For labeling
        ax[1].plot_date(dates, values, '#040405', label = etiqueta, lw=2) 
        ax[1].set_xlim(x_minima,x_maxima)
        
    # Second axis (ax[1]) configuration:
        years = mdates.YearLocator()
        years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('\n%Y')
        ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
        ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
        months = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=2)
        months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m')
        ax[1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
        ax[1].xaxis.set_minor_formatter(months_fmt)
        ax[1].tick_params(which = 'major', labelsize=17)
        ax[1].tick_params(which = 'minor', labelsize=15,)
        ax[1].legend(framealpha=1, borderpad = 0.7, frameon = True,
            labelspacing = 0.7, fontsize = 18, loc='best')
        ax[1].grid(axis='y')
        ax[1].grid(which='minor')
        ax[1].set_ylabel("Piezometría (m)", fontsize = 22, labelpad = 11)
    
        # Figure saving:
        directorio = os.path.dirname(nombreSalida)
        dir_destino = os.path.join(directorio, ("Gráficas " + zona + "/"))
        if not os.path.isdir(dir_destino):
            os.makedirs(dir_destino)
        imagen = (i.getAgregado() + '-P-' + str(l) + ".png")
        plt.savefig(dir_destino + imagen)
        
        plt.cla()   # Close last axis
    plt.clf()
    plt.close(fig)
```

Nevertheless, only the upper figure is shown. I do not know what could be happening, so I'd really aprecciate someone's help.
A curious thing happening is that `plt.show()` only works when second loop is not reached yet; within the second loop, `plt.show()` does not works. Outside the nested loop, second loop plots are shown correctly.

[This link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1jwg.png) allows to watch the erroneous result.

Comment: Just point out your commet: [plt.cla()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.cla.html) doesn't close last axis. It clears current axes. See my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63535394/10315163) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved out. In case anyone is interested in, figure was not shown because dates were on pandas format. I've had to transformed them into matplotlib format (ie, number format), through this code line:

```
dates = [date2num(datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d')) for i in dates]
```